# How to store information about the date when player was added to team

Tags: java, store, localdate

I have a problem. I dont know how to store current `LocalDate` in my program.

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Footballer extends Person {

    private int age;
    private List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Footballer(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public void addTeam (Team team1) throws IOException {
        teams.add(team1);
        team1.addFootballer(this);
    }

}
```

And similar class `Team`. I want to store `LocalDate` when method `addTeam` was called. How to do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Store it where?

Comment: You need bridging class between player and team to represent the player being on the team. Say, `PlayerOnTeam` or simply `TeamPlayer`. Then an object of the bridging class can contain your `LocalDate`. Search and read about many-to-many relations in Java.

Comment: ok i have this class and do relations in it but how to do method to call like getDataWhenPlayerAdd() ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a property of Footballer, you can add a LocalDate property to the class, then set it when the addTeam is invoked, and finally add a getter for that field. E.g.

```
public class Footballer extends Person {

   private int age;
   private List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();
   private LocalDate dateWhenPlayerAdd = null;

   public Footballer(int age) {
       this.age = age;
   }

   public void addTeam (Team team1) throws IOException {
       teams.add(team1);
       this.dateWhenPlayerAdd=LocalDate.now();
       team1.addFootballer(this);
   }

   public LocalDate getDateWhenPlayerAdd() {
       return this.dateWhenPlayerAdd;
   }
}
```

Comment: ok but what happened when I add two players in different date? and i want to call this method on a specific team or footballer

Comment: If you add two players on different dates, they have their own dates. You didn't ask about the team, but in case you can add a function on the Team object returning the list of players.